# Finding a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_j\}$ be an arbitrary sequence of positive real functions on $\mathbb{R}$. How can I find a function $f$ so that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{f_n(x)}=\infty$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For example, for every $n\ge 1$, let $f(x)=n(f_1(x)+\cdots +f_n(x))$ when $n-1\le|x|<n$.

Comment: Notice that $n$ is changing and $f$ must not depend on $n$.

Comment: @bigli: $f$ is independent of $n$. Please check my definition.

Comment: For example: Let $n=10$, then what's the limit $\dfrac{f(x)}{f_{1000}(x)}$ as $x\to\pm\infty$???

Comment: @bigli: I am afraid you didn't understand my definition of $f$ correctly. Note that in the definition of $f$, $n$ is dependent on $x$(but independent of $f$), i.e. $n$ is unique positive integer such that $|x|\in[n-1,n)$.  By definition, for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x\in \Bbb R$, if $|x|\in[m-1,m)$, then $\frac{f(x)}{f_n(x)}>m$, which implies your result.

Comment: Please present more details. I think something is mistake. I do not find out your $f$.  !!!

Comment: @bigli: My last comment is flawed($m$ there should be no less than $n$), but the definition of $f$ is no problem. Given $x\in\Bbb R$, there exists a unique $n\in\Bbb N$, such that $n-1\le |x|<n$, and for this $x$ and assoicated $n$, by definition,  $f(x)=n(f_1(x)+\cdots f_n(x))$, and hence $f(x)>nf_k(x)$ for $1\le k\le n$. Now let us show that for every $n\in\Bbb N$, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{f_n(x)}=+\infty$. It follows from the fact that when $|x|\ge m-1>n$, $f(x)>mf_n(x)$.

Comment: Your definition for $f$ is very very interesting. But I think that  its details should is changed. Let me start. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{f_n(x)}=+\infty$ is equivalent with $\forall \alpha>0 \exists \beta>0 ; \forall x$ if $x>\beta$ then $\dfrac{f(x)}{f_n(x)}>\alpha$. Now let $\alpha$ is chosen arbitrarily, so there exist $m\in\mathbb{N}; m>\alpha$. Now let $\beta:=\max\{m,n\}$ so if $x>\beta$ then $\exists j ; \beta+j\leq x<\beta+j+1$  and so $f(x)>(\beta+j)f_k(x)$ for $1\leq k\leq \beta+j$. Because $1\leq n\leq \beta+j$ so $\dfrac{f(x)}{f_n(x)}>(\beta+j)>m>\alpha$ .

Comment: @bigli: Your argument is totally correct! I think the argument in my last comment is also correct, although not as detailed as yours. If you wish, could you please do me a favor to [accept](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/53845) my answer?

Comment: I appreciate your answer, concern and pursuit. I'm really so excited for your the function $f$, very brilliant.

Comment: @bigli: Thank you for your appreciation.